# Finding the index of a value from a random dimensional array

Tags: c, algorithm, math

```
int getIndex(int a[], int size, int value)
{
    int index = 0;

    while (index < size && a[index] != value)
    {
        ++index;
    }

    return (index == size ? -1 : index);
}
```

Here is a method that returns the index of a value inside an array. I want to have a method that does this for any dimension. How can I make it universal? Or is it even possible at all?

Comment: can you be more clear?

Comment: you can pass array of any size to this method, providing you change size to be of size_t type

Comment: What do you mean by "dimension"?

Comment: You want to find indices `i` and `j` in an `int array[10][10]` for example?

Comment: @DennisvonEich Then you mean "for any number of dimensions" not "for any dimension"

Comment: @return84 I am sorry, you are right.

Comment: The array is nothing more than a bunch of elements stored in memory consecutively. That means that you can pass only the first element to the function, while keeping track of the array size of course. That way you can iterate though all the elements by only one loop, without depending on the array dimension.

Comment: @Dennis von Eich Please check my answer for more generic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always pass a pointer to the first element of a multi dimensional array and the number of all elements in it, i.e. the product of the sizes in each dimension. From there the algorithm is as in a one dimensional array.

The elements in an array, also in a multi-dimensional array, are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory.

The return value would be a single index; the function would not know about the number of dimensions and their sizes. The caller would have to reconstruct the indices in each the array's dimension from the "flat" overall index of the found element; e.g. for a `int arr[2][5]`, a return value of 8 would correspond to element `arr[1][2]`. The relationship between "flat" index and multi-dimensional index tuples is (of course) bijective.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define DIM1 2
#define DIM2 5

int arr[DIM1][DIM2]; // zero-initialized

 // note: for a paramater, int a[] means int *a
int getIndex(int a[], int size, int value)
{
    int index = 0;

    while (index < size && a[index] != value)
    {
        ++index;
    }

    return (index == size ? -1 : index);
}

int main() 
{
    arr[1][2] = 1;

    int index = getIndex(arr[0], DIM1*DIM2, 1);

    if(index >= 0)
    {
        int dim1 = index/DIM2;
        int dim2 = index%DIM2; // modulo resp. remainder

        printf("found a 1 at [%d][%d]\n", dim1, dim2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Could not find 1 in arr\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample session:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o multi-arr multi-arr.c && ./multi-arr
found a 1 at [1][2]
```

Comment: Just a minor flaw: if the value is AT index 0 then you will still print "Not found"!

Comment: +1 for simplicity. However I would recommend you to check for `index != -1` because otherwise you could get a wrong result as Daan pointed out.

Comment: @Dennis von Eich Please check my answer for more generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Generic version. Can be ran with any number of dimensions. Treats 1-dimensional array as multi dimensional space so that same region of memory can be looked in different ways.

Complete example can be found [here](https://github.com/spinlockirqsave/c/tree/master/array_find).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int get_idx(int a[], uint32_t dims[], uint32_t dims_n, int value)
{
    size_t size;
    size_t index = 0, n;

    if (dims[0] < 1) return -1;
    size = 1;
    n = dims_n;
    while (n)
        size *= dims[--n];

    if (dims_n > size) return -1;

    while (index < size && a[index] != value)
    {
        ++index;
    }

    if (index == size)
       return  -1;
    n = 0;
    while (n < dims_n)
    {
        size /= dims[n];
        dims[n] = index / size;
        index = index % size;
        ++n;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
int
main(void) {
    int res;
    uint32_t dims[5];
    int a[12] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };

    dims[0] = 12;
    res = get_idx(a, dims, 1, 10);
    if (res == -1) goto fail;
    printf("dim1 [%u]\n", dims[0]);

    dims[0] = 2;
    dims[1] = 6;
    res = get_idx(a, dims, 2, 10);
    if (res == -1) goto fail;
    printf("dim1 [%u] dim2 [%u]\n", dims[0], dims[1]);

    dims[0] = 3;
    dims[1] = 2;
    dims[2] = 2;
    res = get_idx(a, dims, 3, 10);
    if (res == -1) goto fail;
    printf("dim1 [%u] dim2 [%u] dim3 [%u]\n", dims[0], dims[1], dims[2]);

    dims[0] = 2;
    dims[1] = 2;
    dims[2] = 2;
    dims[3] = 2;
    res = get_idx(a, dims, 4, 10);
    if (res == -1) goto fail;
    printf("dim1 [%u] dim2 [%u] dim3 [%u] dim4 [%u]\n",
                       dims[0], dims[1], dims[2], dims[3]);
    return 0;
fail:
    printf("Not found\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Output:

dim1 [10]

dim1 [1] dim2 [4]

dim1 [2] dim2 [1] dim3 [0]

dim1 [1] dim2 [0] dim3 [1] dim4 [0]

Answer (score 0):

The array is nothing more than a bunch of elements stored in memory consecutively (applies to any dimension). That means that you can pass only the first element to the function, while keeping track of the array size, of course. That way you can iterate though all the elements by only one loop, without depending on the array dimension

Example of filling in a multi-dimensional array:

```
int matrix[50][100];
int *iptr = NULL;
int i = 0;

// sets first matrix to: 
// row 0:   0,   1,   2, ...,  99 
// row 1: 100, 110, 120, ..., 199
//        ...
iptr = &(matrix[0][0]);
for(i=0; i < 50*100; i++) 
{
    *iptr = i;
    iptr++;  
}
```

Comment: I think `int[][] matrix = new int[50][100];` may be C# syntax.

Comment: I come from C# world, my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just return the address of the element you want ?

```
int *getIndex(int a[], int size, int value)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    if (a[i] == value) {
      return (a + i);
    }
  }
  return (NULL);
}
```

You can have any multidimentionnal array you want, it doesn't matter anymore.